# What's the purpose of singleton_class.send & singleton_class.class_eval in this metaprogramming example?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
 set_table_name 'produce'
end

module ActiveRecord
  class Base
    def self.set_table_name name
    define_attr_method :table_name, name
  end

  def self.define_attr_method(name, value)
    singleton_class.send :alias_method, "original_#{name}", name
    singleton_class.class_eval do
      define_method(name) do
        value
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I'd like to understand how `set_table_name` becomes defined in this example.

Why is `singleton_class.send` needed here?

And why is `class_eval` called on `singleton_class` instead of on `self`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for using "singleton_class" is because you do not want to modify the ActiveRecord::Base class, but the Product class.

More info about metaptogramming and singleton class here: http://whytheluckystiff.net/articles/seeingMetaclassesClearly.html

Comment: Archived version of this extinct _why link: http://web.archive.org/web/20090615044849/http://whytheluckystiff.net/articles/seeingMetaclassesClearly.html